# How can I force user to enter negative number in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I force user to enter negative number in Excel?

Basically column A can only be "W" or "X". Whenever column A has "W", i want column B to reflect a negative number, even if the user has keyed in a positive number.

"W" in column A corresponds to a negative value in column B

"X" in column B corresponds to a positive value in column B.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just write a formula in column C to show the wrong imports. the easiest way

Comment: Welcome to SO kangaroo! Can you clarify your question? The title says you want to force the user to enter a negative integer, but then you said you "want column B to reflect a negative number, even if the user has keyed in a positive number". So do you want to accept positive inputs then negate them if positive?

Comment: @technoman23 Thank you for your comments! Nope, I do NOT want to negate a positive number to negative, more like column B has to be a negative number if column A is "W". I ask this because my colleagues always neglect the negative sign so this is to prevent my colleagues from making mistakes and accidentally keyed in positive value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No VBA needed. Just use [data validation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) with the following formula

```
=OR(AND(A1="W",B1<0),AND(A1="X",B1>0))
```

[image]

*<sup>Image 1: Using data validation `W` in column A only allows negatives in column B, `X` in column A only allows positives in column B.</sup>*

Comment: @PEH Yes it works!! Really appreciate your help :) However, just one doubt, this method does not work on existing data? For example, I already have 300 rows of data, when I highlight Column B and apply the rules, it does not work when I key in data into 301th row. but it works on a blank sheet.

Comment: Well it should work if you apply the formula for data validation correctly. In the formula you enter `A1` and `B1` need the row number of the first cell you apply the validation rule to. So If you apply it to the entire column B, the formula should work. If you apply it to range B5:B500 then the `A1` and `B1` need to be adjusted to `A5` and `B5` to work properly. Of coures this only checks the values at the moment you enter the data. It does no checks if `W` or `X` changes and it does not check existing data. • But you asked to ckeck when user "enters" data, so this answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Install the code below in the code module of the worksheet on which you want to control the input. It's a module that already exists in your VB Project. Any module you have to create is the wrong one and won't work. Look for a module with a double name like *Sheet1 (Sheet1)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 058

    Dim Rng         As Range
    Dim Numb        As Variant
    Dim NewNumb     As Double
    
    ' ignore changes to more than one cell (such as pasting)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' this range starts in A2 and covers all used cells in  columns A:B
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
                    .Resize(, 2)
    ' skip if the changed cell is not within the defiend range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        ' take no action of the value in column A isn't "X" or "W"
        With Target
            Numb = Cells(.Row, "B").Value
            ' take no action if the cell in column B has no value
            If Numb Then
                If Cells(.Row, "A").Value = "W" Then
                    NewNumb = Abs(Val(Numb)) * -1
                ElseIf Cells(.Row, "A").Value = "X" Then
                    NewNumb = Abs(Val(Numb))
                End If
            
                ' prevent changes made from calling this procedure
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                ' don't take action if the value in column A
                ' was neither X nor W
                If Numb And (Numb <> NewNumb) Then _
                    Cells(.Row, "B").Value = NewNumb
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The code works on columns A and B. To modify these targets isn't difficult. For now, when a cell in either column is changed the procedure may take action. For the rules by which it will *not* take action please read the comments in the code. When it does take action it will make sure that any entry in column B is negative if the letter in column A is *W* and positive when it's *X*, regardless of what sign the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

A little VBA in your worksheet module will take care of that:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const SourceColumn  As Long = 1
    Const TargetColumn  As Long = 2
    Const NegatorSymbol As String = "W"
    
    Dim SourceRange     As Excel.Range
    Dim TargetRange     As Excel.Range
    Dim Sign            As Long
    Dim TargetValue     As Long
    
    If Target.Column = TargetColumn Then
        Set SourceRange = Cells(Target.Row, SourceColumn)
        If UCase(SourceRange.Value) = NegatorSymbol Then
            Sign = -1
        Else
            Sign = 1
        End If
        TargetValue = Sign * Abs(Target.Value)
        If Target.Value <> TargetValue Then
            Target.Value = TargetValue
        End If
    ElseIf Target.Column = SourceColumn Then
        Set TargetRange = Cells(Target.Row, TargetColumn)
        If UCase(Target.Value) = NegatorSymbol Then
            Sign = -1
        Else
            Sign = 1
        End If
        TargetValue = Sign * Abs(TargetRange.Value)
        If TargetRange.Value <> TargetValue Then
            TargetRange.Value = TargetValue
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set on column B a data validation Custom with this formula:

```
=OR(AND(A1="W";B1<0);AND(A1<>"W";B1>0))
```

[EDIT]

I was late to the party...